# Use cURL to call controller in CodeIgniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

Okay so this problem is bothering me quite a bit.

I've created a controller function in my CodeIgniter projects at [project_url]/admin/orderpicking/get_updated_statuses

function name: get_updated_statuses
controller name: Orderpicking.php
controller location: application/admin

Inside the controller all I have is

```
ob_start();
print_r('success');
file_put_contents('file.txt', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

to confirm that I am hitting the controller.

When I hit the controller directly from my browser, the file gets created with 'success' as the content.

When I use cURL from another project to hit the controller, nothing happens, the result is an empty string (I dont care about the result right now, but the file.txt file is no longer being created).

Code that calls the controller is as follows:

```
$data = array('datetime'=>new DateTime());
        $header = array(
            'Identification:Portal::ReadAPI', // TODO config
            'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencode'
        );
        $url = '[local instance]/admin/orderpicking/get_updated_statuses'; // TODO config

        $curlGetUpdatedItems = curl_init($url);
        /** CURL OPTIONS */
        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(serialize($data)));
        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
//        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
//        curl_setopt($curlGetUpdatedItems, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $certificate_location);
        /** CURL OPTIONS */

        $result = curl_exec($curlGetUpdatedItems);
```

Are there any obvious mistakes I'm making here? 
I will add in a certificate later when I make the portal https but until then I don't think I need it?

Any help and/or advice is extremely welcome!

**----- UPDATE -----**

After var_dump'ing the result I've noticed that a boolean true is returned.
`curl_error($curlGetUpdatedItems)` returns an empty string.

Comment: Where is this "other project"? localhost is not accessible from outside of your own PC. Do you have a local DNS entry set up so that other things can find your localhost?

Comment: From your "other project" try [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on everywhere? Have you checked your web server access logs?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus everything is currently local.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've updated my original post with more information regarding possible errors that could have occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it make by steps:

```
$data_string = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($result,true);
```

don't know if need the header, i think that the default already is application/x-www-form-urlencode

id it not works, try changing the $data values in array. think helps . :)